# Why can't I add scatter points to my plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

Data I'm working with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xb7icmocz-SD2Rkq4ykTZowxW0uFFhBl/view?usp=sharing

I can't figure out why my code does not work. The problem is showing when I try to add the dataframes 'higher' and 'lower' to my plot. I believe I'm making a very basic mistake but can't figure out what it is. Any ideas??

For some general context, I would like to plot as point the data for the days in 2015 where the min/max temperature was lower/higher than in the 2005-2014 period.

Would highly appreciate any help!!

```
get_ipython().magic("matplotlib inline")

df = pd.read_csv("data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv")

df['degrees']=df['Data_Value']/10

df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df2 = df[df['Date']<'2015-01-01']

df3 = df[df['Date']>='2015-01-01']

fmt_str = '%m-%d'
max_temp = df2.groupby(df2.Date.dt.strftime(fmt_str))['degrees'].max()
min_temp = df2.groupby(df2.Date.dt.strftime(fmt_str))['degrees'].min()

max_temp=max_temp.drop('02-29')
min_temp=min_temp.drop('02-29')

max_temp2 = df3.groupby(df3.Date.dt.strftime(fmt_str))['degrees'].max()
min_temp2 = df3.groupby(df3.Date.dt.strftime(fmt_str))['degrees'].min()

dfmin = min_temp.to_frame().reset_index()
dfmin2 = min_temp2.to_frame().reset_index()
dfmax = max_temp.to_frame().reset_index()
dfmax2 = max_temp2.to_frame().reset_index()

lower = dfmin2[dfmin2['degrees']<dfmin['degrees']]
higher = dfmax2[dfmax2['degrees']>dfmax['degrees']]

max_temp.plot(x ='Date', y='degrees', kind = 'line')
min_temp.plot(x ='Date',y='degrees', kind= 'line')

lower.plot(x = 'Date', y='degrees', kind='scatter')
higher.plot(x = 'Date', y='degrees', kind='scatter')

plt.fill_between(range(len(min_temp)),min_temp, max_temp, color='C0', alpha=0.2)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set(xlabel="Date",
       ylabel="Temperature",
       title="Extreme Weather in 2015")

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

x = plt.gca().xaxis

ax.legend(['Record high temperatures 2005-2014', 'Record low temperatures 2005-2014'])

month=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
DayOfMonth=[1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335]
plt.xticks(DayOfMonth)
plt.xticks(DayOfMonth,month)

for item in x.get_ticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)

plt.show()
```